# selenium webdriver gives error in pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using following code with python3.7 in pycharm.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
```

But I get following error,

```
  File "C:/D/Project Documentation/Webdaq_504_Software/python_code/seleniumScripts/firstSeleniumsScript.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

But if I run same code line by line in python shell, it works correctly. Why I'm unable to run it in pycharm. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything. But nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried it with Py3.6? There are lots of libraries that haven't been updated yet, In your python shell, type "which python" and see if you are indeed using Py3.7.

Comment: it is 3.7, 64-bit, for sure
https://imgur.com/a/UnYaitL

Comment: check selenium is installed with pip?

Comment: pycharm is not using the interpreter you have selenium installed into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that you should have the [webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) in the same folder of your script or specify a different path this way:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "your/webdriver/path")
```

Here's a very minimal example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

**Important checks**

- Also check if you named your script webdriver.py or selenium.py.
  That will cause issues in dependencies, be sure to rename it with a different name.
- Do not put your chromedriver.exe in C:\ this can lead to issues too

**Update**

As you can read [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started):

Ensure Chromium/Google Chrome is installed in a recognized location
ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for your platform. You can also force ChromeDriver to use a custom location [by setting a special capability](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location).

Comment: moved to another folder instead of C, then tried same folder as the script, but still same error, also the script name is "firstSeleniumsScript.py",

Comment: @Salman
Please remove and reinstall selenium: pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall selenium

Comment: @Salman Did my answer help? If this is the case kindly upvote it and / or choose it as the right one

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add executable_path parameter,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER")
```

Comment: So, What is an exception

Comment: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome',
this is the error that I'm receiving, it only occurs in pycharm, if run the script from windows cmd using "python filename.py", it works right

Comment: @Salman It might be possibility of incompitibility between Selenium and Chrome version. Please upgrade Selenium verison to 3.13 or 3.12

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("http://mail.google.com")
```